# package.json start scripts failing react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have two package.json files, one in my root directory, and one in my react-web directory...

heres the scripts:

root directory package.json

```
"start": "cd react-web && npm run postinstall && export REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_ENVIRONMENT=gianlucaherokutest320880 && npm start"
```

react-web directory package.json

```
   "start": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 react-app-rewired start",
```

it gives me this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/react-web/react-app-rewired'
```

However, I have `react-app-rewired` installed, and I deleted `node_modules` and `npm install` again already! Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try react-scripts instead

Comment: @Gianluca unfortunately it does the same thing.